# Where does energy go when not enough voltage is applied to charge a battery?

Tags: voltage, batteries, motor, dc

Currently I am working on creating a DC motor that when manually cranked, or spun, will charge a rechargeable battery. Through some research I found the only way to charge a rechargeable battery is by supplying more voltage than the battery currently has to the battery.

My question is, if I spun a DC motor to create a current that is 2.0V into a battery that is 1.2V what happens to the energy (spinning DC motor) when the voltage slows down to below 1.2V?

Comment: When you ask "where does energy go", it's usually heat. But this is just a guess, don't take it as an educated answer.

Comment: That is what I assumed, one other possible solution I theorized was the energy circulating through the circuit back into the motor and powering the motor. Any thoughts on whether that's even possible or plausible?

Comment: If you're not spinning the motor fast enough to generate 1.2V, the energy doesn't go anywhere, you just aren't expending any (over and above what you need to overcome the motor's friction).

Comment: So what you are saying is when I do exceed 1.2V the DC motor will encounter more resistance than when below and that is the energy being put into the battery? Kind of like a load?

Comment: _”current that is 2.0V”_ No such thing. Current is measure in ampere (A). Tention/voltage is measured in volt (V).

Comment: Just a error in communication there, I am very new to electronics however I do understand that current, voltage, and amps are different things. Im just not experienced enough to recognize it yet when I am talking.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect time to learn and then update your question!

Answer (score 1):

In general, to charge a battery, you need to apply a slightly **higher** voltage to the battery than the current battery's voltage.

So if the battery is 1.2 V, you will need to apply more than 1.2 V. For example if you would apply 1.3 V then that would make **current** flow from your 1.3 V source **into** the 1.2 V battery. Since the current flows into the battery that means that also **energy** is flowing into the battery.

It is important to **limit** that charging current so applying 2 V without any **series resistance** to limit the current might cause the charging current to become **too high** and **damage** the battery and/or DC motor. It depends on the situation though, if your DC motor is small and can only supply say 1 A but your battery is very large and can handle a 10 A charging current, then obviously there would be no issue.

If you try to charge with 1.2 V then almost **no current** would flow as the voltages of the source (your DC motor) and battery are **equal**.

If you would apply **no power** to that DC motor, obviously the 1.2 V of the battery would make it spin. The battery would be discharged.

Comment: so if I were to be generating 1.0V using my DC Motor with a diode preventing energy from traveling from the battery since it has 1.2V, the energy I am generating would be wasted into heat?

Comment: No, the diode would prevent current from flowing. As Power = Voltage x Current. Current = 0 so Power is 0 as well. **There will be no heat generated or wasted**. The only energy needed is the amount that is needed to keep the DC motor rotating (to overcome friction losses etc.). The situation would be similar to just spinning the motor without anything connected to the electrical contacts.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

The energy will be absorbed by the rotor shaft as kinetic energy, thus accelerating it.

**Long answer:**

To unravel the mistery, we must model your situation first. The DC motor can be modelled as a voltage source in series with a resistance:
[image]

By connecting the motor directly to the battery you are making the following circuit:
[image]

The motor voltage is proportional to the shaft speed \$\omega\$:
$$
V_{motor} = K \times \omega
$$

If the motor voltage is greater than the battery voltage, current will flow from the motor to the battery, charging it. The energy entering the battery comes from the motor voltage, which in turns comes from the mechanical energy required to move the motor shaft.

On the other hand, if the battery voltage is greater than the motor voltage, current will flow from the battery to the motor, effectively discharging the battery. The energy leaving the battery will be absorbed by the motor voltage and converted in mechanical energy. This mechanical energy will accelerate the motor shaft until its speed makes the motor voltage equal to the battery voltage, stopping the current flow (strictly speaking, the motor voltage will rise until being slightly lower than the battery voltage). In this situation the motor will be running using the battery's energy.

If you want to prevent this scenario, a simple solution is using a diode in series to prevent a reverse current flow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A motor and a generator are more or less the same device, just optimized for a different application. So ask, what happens if a battery is connected to a motor, and where does the energy go?

Ideally, the chemical power out of the battery (voltage times current) equals the mechanical power generated by the motor (angular velocity times torque).

What the chemical energy becomes depends on what's connected to the motor.

For example, if a brake is connected to the motor you get friction, and thermal energy.

If a pump is connected to the motor you could pump water uphill, making gravitational potential energy.

If a flywheel is connected to the motor you could increase its speed, making kinetic energy.

In practice some fraction of the energy is always lost to friction and resistive losses in the wires, motor windings, and internals of the battery, making thermal energy. If the motor is locked such that it can't spin, angular velocity and thus mechanical power must be zero, and *all* the chemical energy goes to heat, just as would happen connecting a resistor across the battery. Only the resistor is the long length of wire in the motor winding.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: nothing.

At 2.0V a current is flowing through the coils to charge the battery. The current flowing through the coil creates a magnetic field that opposes the magnetic field of the rotor, resulting in a force on the rotor opposite the direction of motion, slowing it down. Once you drop below 1.2V, the current stops flowing (assuming you have a diode or something similar). With no current flowing the force against the rotor goes away and the rotor will turn forever if we ignore friction. The energy hasn't gone away, it's just stored as kinetic energy of the rotor, similar to a fly-wheel. If we include friction, then the kinetic energy is slowly converted to heat and dissipated.